# How can one clear all the keyframes in an After Effects script?

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I am writing a script for After Effects where as one of the steps I need to clear all the keyframes in . I currently have

```
for (highestIndex = prop.numKeys; highestIndex > 0; highestIndex--) {
    prop.removeKey(highestIndex);
}
```

which works fine, except that it takes a few (very noticeable) seconds to run. In the GUI, there is the little stopwatch next to the property that can clear all the keyframes quickly. The property `isTimeVarying` (bool indicating if there are any keyframes) is read only, and I can't seem to find a `setTimeVarying` or similar method. Is there a way to do said thing?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using menu commands, but you've got to be very careful about what is selected and what is not, and be very sure that the comp is open in a viewer, and the viewer is active. For that, you'll need at least CS6.

```
function removeAllKeys(props){

    var deselectAllId = app.findMenuCommandId("Deselect All");
    var clearId = app.findMenuCommandId("Clear");
    var comp, oldSelection, i;

    // assumed: all props belong to the same comp
    if (props.length===0) return;

    comp = props[0].propertyGroup(props[0].propertyDepth).containingComp;
    oldSelection = comp.selectedProperties;

    app.beginUndoGroup("Remove All Keys");
    // make sure that the comp is open in a viewer (essential, otherwise: catastrophy)
    comp.openInViewer();
    // deselect everything:
    app.executeCommand(deselectAllId);
    for (i=0; i<props.length; i++){
        if (props[i].numKeys>0){
            props[i].selected = true;
            app.executeCommand(clearId);
            app.executeCommand(deselectAllId);
            };
        };
    for (i=0; i<oldSelection.length; i++){
        oldSelection[i].selected = true;
        };
    app.endUndoGroup();
    return;
    };

removeAllKeys(app.project.activeItem.selectedProperties);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the argument is expected to be an array of properties. It is to avoid to repeat the openInViewer/deselectAll several times, and to be able to eventually recover the old selection.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
var targetComp = app.project.activeItem; // Collect the active composition
var selectedLayer = targetComp.selectedLayers; // Collect the selected layers

// Identify the target parameter to be deleted
var targetParam = selectedLayer[0].transform.position; // Target the Position paramter of the first selected layer

// A. Delete the Keyframes forward from FIRST frame to LAST frame
while (targetParam.numKeys != 0) { // While there are still Keyframes, continue looping
    targetParam.removeKey(1); // Delete the first Keyframe
}

// B. Delete the Keyframes backward from LAST frame to FIRST frame
for (i = targetParam.numKeys; i != 0; i--) { // Cycle through the Keyframes
    targetParam.removeKey(i); // Remove the current Keyframe
}
```

You only need either A or B depending on whether you want to cycle forward and end up with the value of the last keyframe or cycle backward and end up with the value of the first keyframe.

Comment: That's (B) essentially the code in the question. The point of the question was to minimize the number of `removeKey` calls (which take a long time) and replace it with a single command that takes next to zero time (as is possible in the GUI).

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the [After Effects Scripting Guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf) page 140 :

> To remove more than one keyframe, you
>   must start with the highest index number and work down to the lowest to ensure that the remaining indices
>   reference the same keyframe after each removal.

So you can't delete more than one keyframe at a time which is really a shame, but if you are looking for a fastest way, I searched and I found nothing so I think there is no better way..

But here is what you can do, you can't delete the keyframes but you can make the animation not change during all the time, you just have to add the expression `valueAtTime(0)`
 to your property like this :

```
yourProperty.expression = "valueAtTime(0)";
```

See the [After Effects Scripting Guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf) page 129.

I hope it helped you :)